# Is there any other place - besides a theme, a plugin, or a mu-plugin - that an option page might conceivably be used?

Tags: options

I'm creating a helper class for simplifying the creation of an option page in admin that could conceivably be used in a theme, a plugin, or a mu-plugin. I'm trying to make the class as easy to instantiate as possible, so I plan on determining programmatically which of those three places the class is being instantiated from.

I haven't come across any other ways an option page might be desirable, but I don't want to leave out a scenario that I just haven't encountered or thought of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are working on WordPress core development you should not be writing anything but a:

1. Theme
2. Child Theme
3. Plugin
4. Mu-Plugin
5. Drop-In

For the last two see: http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/must-use-and-drop-ins-plugins/

I am out on a limb a little bit here but I think that is the exhaustive list, with the first three by far the most common.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly why I posted a Question. I've been doing a lot of learning re: WordPress in the last two months, read countless posts in SE, wordpress.org, various blogs, etc., and still hadn't come across the `Drop-In` functionality. Learn something new every Question! I think I might not code for it, since my class, while very helpful as a *starting point*, likely wouldn't be used by many who are using Drop-Ins. But if demand calls for it I will surely include it.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer - NO. 
However each developer may choose different places for option screens .

You should take a look to this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/option-tree/ which is used by many theme creators.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Adrian7. I'll look it through. At first glance it seems a more complex concept & functionality than I'm aiming for. I'm not (yet!) trying to write an all-in-one option page plugin with the kitchen sink thrown in, more like a quick way to be able to create the option page with a minimal amount of coding. For instance, say you want a link to your option page in the plugin listing, as well as include stylesheets/js on your option page, and maybe have it a top-level menu item, with icon, in a specific spot. My class does that with minimal user coding.

Comment: You seem very confident on your "minimal" coding stuff :P.  Make a plugin, post it on the plugins directory and pay attention to the reviews - then you'll know if it's worthy!

Comment: Confident? Not so much. But I'll definitely put it out for the world to judge, soon. At least to start, what I'm trying to go for is something in the plugin world akin to what [**_s**](http://underscores.me/) (underscores starter theme) is to theme creation. An easy to implement starting point that's properly coded. But time (and user reception) will tell what it ultimately becomes. :)